# On what frameworks are sites like Cryptokitties made?

Tags: solidity, javascript, cryptokitties

Game contracts are written on Solidity. On what frameworks are sites like Cryptokitties and other games made? (Node js, React, Vue or something else?)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript library [Web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) has been developed specifically for Ethereum dapps. I don't think there's any competing JS frameworks for Ethereum at this time. Web3.js can be used in conjunction with a variety of JavaScript frameworks including the ones that you've mentioned, but Web3.js is the crucial JS library for connecting to Ethereum.

Comment: Also on the server side you can use web3.py https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py and other Web3 frameworks for your choice of programming language.

Comment: ^ Good point. I've also seen people using [web3j](https://web3j.io/) for Java and Android apps.